# Capture parameter on url and change action form and link parameter only with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

Example:

http://example.com/?**myparameter**

Have parameter list:

myparameterA 
myparameterB 
 
myparameterC

and need change parameter here:

```
<form id="signup" name="signup" method="GET" action="http://example.com/visitor/promochild=myparameter">
```

and here:

```
<a href="http://example.com/visitor/promochild=myparameter">Link</a>
```

myparameter on link and form are variable.

And i can check if the parameter on url exists on my list? with hashmap or arraylist maybe?

how i can do that with javascript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Extract your parameter from the url and then use indexOf in the parameter array.

```
function myFunc(){
        var parameterType="promochild";
        var url=document.getElementById("linkId").href;
        var index=url.search(parameterType);   //search for parameterType in url
        var parameter=url.substr(index+parameterType.length+1);//find index of start of your parameter and extract it

        var parameterList=["parameter1", "parameter2"];
          if(parameterList.indexOf(parameter)!=-1){
            alert("Parameter is present");
          }else{
           alert("Parameter not present in list!!");
         }
        }
```

for the element:

```
<a href="http://example.com/visitor/promochild=parameter1" onclick="myFunc()" id="linkId">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Navish, but i need change parameter on form too, and i can't put id on link =/,

I think I missed to explain that according to the url parameter must change the parameter in the form and the link, this an example of the link that i have https://example.com/indexb.html?eos=yes&skin=bkp/visitor/pf&promochild=USANAOBKPASS&prd=100GB&sg=300236800&sa=OPEN&cmpid=online&dest=REDIR|https://example.com.br/new-page.html

If i have the ABC value on url (http://example.com/?ABC), need to change the parameter of promochild=USANAOBKPASS to promochild=ABC

Comment: If you cannot use Id then you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("a");` to get the element in the `var url` if you have only one `<a>` anchor tag on your html.